# IE Friendly Way in jQuery to determine if an element is empty or only contains whitespace or other empty elements?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, trim

I've found plenty of other topics similar to this one, but I they are all slightly unique... so here goes:

I'm trying to construct an IF statement based on whether an element is empty.  However, since the CMS I'm working with will still output empty space, my IF statement needs to be able to recognize empty white space and empty children elements as still "empty" as far as the parent element is concerned.

This is the code I have - and it works well in modern browsers, but it's **not working IE 7/8**.  I've read that there **might be issues with "trim" in IE**?

Any ideas on an alternative solution that will work with IE?

```
$('.items').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.the-element-to-check-for-emptiness').html().trim()) {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Basically, I'm hiding all ".items" by default, and then if their "the-element-to-check-for-emptiness" element has any content I un-hide the item.

Any input is appreciated,
Thanks!

UPDATE

After the insight from James I've updated my code to change the call to "trim" but now the IF statement appears to always evaluate to false no matter what.  Any ideas?

```
$('.items').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.the-element-to-check-for-emptiness').html()$.trim()) {
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE doesn't have `trim`, use jquery's `$.trim()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

```
$.trim($(this).find('.the-element-to-check-for-emptiness').html())
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've added an "updated" portion to my original post - after using $.trim the statement always evaluates to false.  Any ideas?

Comment: You used trim wrong, you can't just slap it on the end.  You pass a string to it.  Have a look at the docs (updating answer).

Comment: @LearnWebCode Surely if the element can contain empty child elements you need to use `.text()` rather than `.html()`, so that it ignores the HTML tags for those child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the CMS is using non-breaking spaces, I would use a regular expression to see if the trimmed. I would recommend this:

```
$('.items').each(function() {
   var val = $(this).find('.the-element-to-check-for-emptiness').html();
   var r = new RegExp('^((&nbsp;)|\\s)*$');
   if (!r.test(val)) {
     $(this).css('display', 'block');
   }
});
```

The regex will find any whitespace or non-breaking space and return true. Therefore, we negate it to find if there is anything else in the element.